# Checking Mail Bock with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

is there any possibility to check a normal mail box with rails?

I want to check if there are new incoming mails, I want to open those and read the text to find a special string in it.

Is this possible? and how?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service provider :) Try to R&D. Post specific errors for better help. Not sure if https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler can help you

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow. Here we expect you to research your topic first, try out any tutorials on the subject, and come back to us then show us the code you have written (even if it is not working), and explain what the error is that you're getting and what you were expecting yourself. We won't write or design your code for you. We won't help you find tutorials or libraries when you can use google for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mail Gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) may helps you.

You can configure Mail to receive email using `retriever_method` within `Mail.defaults`:

```
Mail.defaults do
retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                      :port       => 995,
                      :user_name  => '<username>',
                      :password   => '<password>',
                      :enable_ssl => true
end
```

You can access incoming email in a number of ways.

The most recent email:

```
Mail.all    #=> Returns an array of all emails
Mail.first  #=> Returns the first unread email
Mail.last   #=> Returns the last unread email
```

Comment: that looks great. Gonna test it. Is there a possibility to check if a mail is read or not in pop mailbox?